# Concatenate specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to concatenate 4 different datasets onto pandas python. I can concatenated them but it results in several of the same column names. How do I only produce only one column of the same name, then multiples?

```
concatenated_dataframes = pd.concat(
    [
        dice.reset_index(drop=True),
        json.reset_index(drop=True),
        flexjobs.reset_index(drop=True),
        indeed.reset_index(drop=True),
        simply.reset_index(drop=True),
    ],
    axis=1,
    ignore_index=True,
)
concatenated_dataframes_columns = [
    list(dice.columns),
    list(json.columns),
    list(flexjobs.columns),
    list (indeed.columns),
    list(simply.columns)
]
    
flatten = lambda nested_lists: [item for sublist in nested_lists for item in sublist]

concatenated_dataframes.columns = flatten(concatenated_dataframes_columns)
df= concatenated_dataframes

This results in 
UNNAMED: 0  TITLE   COMPANY     DESCRIPTION     LOCATION    TITLE   JOBLOCATION     POSTEDDATE  DETAILSPAGEURL  COMPANYPAGEURL  COMPANYLOGOURL  SALARY  CLIENTBRANDID   COMPANYNAME     EMPLOYMENTTYPE  SUMMARY     SCORE   EASYAPPLY   EMPLOYERTYPE    WORKFROMHOMEAVAILABILITY    ISREMOTE    UNNAMED: 0  TITLE   SALARY  JOBTYPE     LOCATION    DESCRIPTION     UNNAMED: 0  TITLE   SALARY  JOBTYPE     DESCRIPTION     LOCATION    UNNAMED: 0  COMPANY     DESCRIPTION     LOCATION    SALARY  TITLE
```

Again, how do i combined all the 'titles' in one column, all the 'location' in one column, and so on? Instead of have multiple of them.

Comment: Have you tried running `pd.concat(...,axis=0)` instead of `axis=1`?

Comment: I get a ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 23 elements, new values have 41 elements

Answer (score 0):

I think we can get away with making a blank dataframe that just has the columns we will want at the end and then `concat()` everything onto it.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

all_columns = list(dice.columns) + list(json.columns) + list(flexjobs.columns) + list(indeed.columns) + list(simply.columns)
all_unique_columns = np.unique(np.array(all_columns)) # this will, as the name suggests, give an end list of just the unique columns. You could run print(all_unique_columns) to make sure it has what you want
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_unique_columns)
df = pd.concat([dice, json, flexjobs, indeed, simply],axis=0)
```

It's a little tricky not having reproducible examples of the dataframes that you have. I tested this on a small mock-up example I put together, but let me know if it works for your more complex example.

Comment: It worked by creating the dataframe but im missing a lot of values for several columns.